# Property in `this.props` unavailable in componentDidMount(), but same property visible in `this`

Tags: reactjs

Here's the simplified version of the component that demonstrates the problem I'm having. I'd like to access `this.props` in `componentDidMount()`, but the property is undefined. It is defined, however, when view it the log when passed only as `this`.

In the `render()` method, `this.props` is available.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as ReadableAPI from '../utils/api'

class ListComments extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted")
    console.log(this.props)
    console.log(this)
  }
  render() {
    console.log("rendered")
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.postId}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ListComments
```

Here's the corresponding console output:

[image: console demonstrating issue]

edit: update title; this.props is not undefined, but a property in this.props is.

Comment: That is strange behavior. And what does explicitly logging `this.props.postId` return? Chrome console logging can be strange, sometimes it logs a "live" instance to the object which updates even after the console log has finished. How are you assigning to props?

Comment: I'm assigning to props via react router to the parent component, `Post`, then to the Child component, see the path here --

`<Route path="/:category/:id" component={Post}/>` --> `<ListComments postId={this.state.post.id}/>`

Logging `this.props.postId` also returned undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the problem:

I assigned the property to the ListComments component via a parent component, Post. Then, in Post, I was erroneously assigning the same `id` to the child component from the component state.:

`<Route path="/:category/:id" component={Post}/>`

`<ListComments postId={this.state.post.id}/>`

I should have instead assigned via the original router parameter:

`<ListComments postId={this.props.match.params.id}/>`